# Match in lagged group in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, match, matching

I'm trying to create a new column that indicates if an ID was present in a previous group. Here's my data:

```
data <- data.table(ID = c(1:3, c(9,2,3,4),c(5,1)),
                   groups = c(rep(c("a", "b", "c"), c(3, 4,2))))
   ID groups
1:  1      a
2:  2      a
3:  3      a
4:  9      b
5:  2      b
6:  3      b
7:  4      b
8:  5      c
9:  1      c
```

I'm not sure how to specify lagged groups. I tried to use `shift`, but it's not working:

```
data[,.(ID=ID,match_lagged=ID %in% shift(ID)),by=groups]
```

Here's my desired result.

The first 3 lines are not matched because there is no previous group. FALSE would also work for these three rows.  ID=4 (in group b) is not matched in group a. ID=5 (in group c) is not matched in group b.

Note that ID 1 in group c is not matched in group b so it should be false even though it exists in group a. This is why `duplicated(data$ID)` does not work. Data from a group has to be matched from the **previous** group.

```
groups ID match_lagged
1:      a  1         NA
2:      a  2         NA
3:      a  3         NA
4:      b  9         FALSE
5:      b  2         TRUE
6:      b  3         TRUE
7:      b  4         FALSE
8:      c  5         FALSE
9:      c  1         FALSE
```

A `dplyr` solution would also work.

Comment: `duplicated(data$ID)` doesn't work?

Comment: @d.b No, data from one group should be matched from the **previous** group. I edited the question to make it more obvious of why `duplicated` does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Number the groups, and then check if the `diff` is equal to one for each `ID`.

```
data[, grp.id := .GRP, by = groups]
data[, match_lagged := c(FALSE, diff(grp.id) == 1), by = ID][
     grp.id == 1, match_lagged := NA][]
#   ID groups grp.id match_lagged
#1:  1      a      1           NA
#2:  2      a      1           NA
#3:  3      a      1           NA
#4:  9      b      2        FALSE
#5:  2      b      2         TRUE
#6:  3      b      2         TRUE
#7:  4      b      2        FALSE
#8:  5      c      3        FALSE
#9:  1      c      3        FALSE
```

This assumes that you find each `ID` only once in each group. If that's not the case you can unique, do the above, and then merge in.

Answer (score 0):

This works. There is probably an easier solution:

```
data <- data.frame(ID = c(1:3, 1:4,c(5,1)),
                   groups = c(rep(c("a", "b", "c"), c(3, 4,2))))

z <- data %>% group_by(groups) %>% summarize(all_vals = list(ID))
z <- z %>% mutate(lagged_id = lag(all_vals,1))

match_lagged <- lapply(1:nrow(z) , function(x) {
  (z$all_vals[x] %>% unlist) %in% (z$lagged_id[x] %>% unlist)
})

data$match_lagged = match_lagged %>% unlist
```